# Hive: Kryo Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm executing one of my HQL query which has few joins, union and insert overwrite operation, which is working fine if I run it just once.
If I execute the same job second time, I'm facing this issue.
Can someone help me to identify in which scenario we get this exception?

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 107
Serialization trace:
rowSchema (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UnionOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushProjectionsAndFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushProjectionsAndFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 107
Serialization trace:
rowSchema (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
parentOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UnionOperator)
childOperators (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator)
aliasToWork (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
```

Comment: Are the tables using any SerDe?

Comment: No, we are not using any external SerDe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid Hive's parallel execution by modifying below property to false.

> **hive.exec.parallel**

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes definitely. Hive normally works fine with Kryo but sometime creates problem in De-serialization of objects during parallel execution. To avoid this you have try any alternative, i have provided one.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'll  you try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `set hive.exec.parallel = false;` and then it ran successfully, although slower. My code is:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN a.did IS NOT NULL THEN a.did ELSE b.did END AS device_id,
    CASE WHEN a.did IS NOT NULL THEN a.package ELSE b.package END AS package,
    CASE WHEN a.did IS NOT NULL THEN a.channel ELSE b.channel END AS channel,
    CASE WHEN a.did IS NOT NULL THEN a.time ELSE b.time END AS time
FROM
    (SELECT
      a1.package,
      a1.did,
      MIN(a1.source) AS channel,
      MIN(a1.time) AS time
    FROM
      (SELECT * FROM thetable
        WHERE date_hour = "20160601"
          AND source_type IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
      ) a1
      JOIN
      (SELECT
        package AS package,
        did AS did,
        MIN(time) AS time
      FROM thetable
      WHERE date_hour = "20160601"
        AND source_type IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
      GROUP BY package, did
      ) min
      ON (a1.package = min.package
        AND a1.did = min.did
        AND a1.time = min.time)
    GROUP BY a1.package, a1.did
    ) a
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
      a1.package,
      a1.did,
      MIN(a1.source) AS channel,
      MIN(a1.time) AS time
    FROM
      (SELECT * FROM thetable
        WHERE date_hour = "20160601"
          AND source_type IN ('D')
      ) a1
      JOIN
      (SELECT
        package AS package,
        did AS did,
        MIN(time) AS time
      FROM thetable
      WHERE date_hour = "20160601"
        AND source_type IN ('D')
      GROUP BY package, did
      ) min
      ON (a1.package = min.package
        AND a1.did = min.did
        AND a1.time = min.time)
    GROUP BY a1.package, a1.did
    ) b
    ON (a.package = b.package AND a.did = b.did);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, infact I did not find how to format then.